# TypeScript error Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to call a function with parameters but get this error:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

My function call:

```js
await chatHistory(stream, "zzz");
```

My function:

```js
export const chatHistory = async ({ chatData, chatId }: any) => {....}
```

Comment: But you gave it two arguments and it takes one? And what you're passing it doesn't match at all what it takes as that argument. Very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you created takes only one argument which is an object i.e. `{chatDate, chatId}`. If you you want two arguments you can use:

`export const chatHistory = async (chatData: any, chatId: any) => {....}`

But if you want to go with your function definition as well, that is also fine. In that case you can use:

`await chatHistory({stream, chatId: "zzz"});`

Answer (score 3):

As i can see in your code example, you have specified only one argument (of type: object).

To make your code work, just try:

`await chatHistory({ stream, chatId: "some-Id" });`

This will satisfy the defined arguments of your exported function